# How disable an error http from server in Angular

Tags: angular, http, throw

I have a question about, in Angular 8 How can I hide the line of http method server link

**auth-interceptor.ts**

```
  private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    let errorMsg;
    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
      errorMsg = err.error.message;
      this.injector.get(Router).navigateByUrl(`/login`);
    }
    return throwError(errorMsg);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("id_token");
    if (token) {
      const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token) });
      return next.handle(authReq).pipe(catchError(err => this.handleAuthError(err)));
    }
    else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```

---

GET http://localhost:3000/api/toto 401 (Unauthorized) -- this line

ERROR Auth failed!*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use try catch block and don't throw error of server to end user.

With this practice you can warn user in any way you want.

And if you don't want write your error message then use:

```
private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
  let errorMsg;
  if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
    errorMsg = err.error.message;
    this.injector.get(Router).navigateByUrl(`/login`);
  }
  errorMsg.replace(Url, '');
  return throwError(errorMsg);
}
```